# Menu bar editor: how to add a target="_blank"?

Tags: user-experience

I need to add some external links to the menu bar and I want them to open in a new tab.

I've unsuccessfully tried variations around `https://domain.net/page?target=_blank`

Is this possible through the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a custom extension following [this doc](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_navigationMenu/) was the best and quickest solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it because it's controlled by an attribute on the `<a>` tag. It would be possible with some extra jquery you add to all pages that updates the `<a>` so it has `<a target="_blank"...>`.

But just a warning some people don't like it when you decide for them. If they want to open in another window they can right-click and choose that.

Comment: thanks Dave, we've done it differently with an extension

Comment: FWIW, if you're using Drupal, you can also do this with the external link module (which implements @Demerit's javascript stratagey). If you're doing it as a general useability policy for the whole site, it makes sense to do it at the theme level instead of hardcoding it into civicrm.